# HELP Let ABC an isosceles right triangle with ABC = 90°. Consider the point P on AB such that $\frac{PA}{PB}=2$. Show that $PA\cdot BP=BQ\cdot BG$.

Tags: geometry, triangles, ratio, median

Let ABC be an isosceles right triangle with ABC = 90°, M and N the midpoints of sides BC and AC, and G is BN intersected by AM. Consider the point P on AB such that $\frac{BM}{BP}=2$. If BN intersects CP in Q, show that $PA\cdot BP=BQ\cdot BG$.

**My ideas:**

*My drawing*

[image]

Okay, so I thought of many things:
1)

> MN being middle line
> Maybe we can use the middle line propriety somewhere.
> 2)
> Center of gravity G

If we take a closer look at the drawing we observe that G is the crossing of two medians.
From this, we can write that :

$BG=\frac{2\cdot BN}{3}$

$PB=\frac{AB}{3}$

ALSO

$BM=\frac{BN}{2}$

From what I wrote above we can write that:

$PB\cdot BM= \frac{AB}{3}\cdot\frac{AB}{2}$

I think we can notate AB as x and then show that $BQ\cdot BG$ equals it.

3)

> The Thales Theorem

We can apply The Thales Theorem in the ABM triangle => PG is parallel with BM.

I don't know what to do forward. Hope one of you can help me. Any ideas are welcome! Thank you!

Comment: The drawing shows PB slightly longer than BQ and PA way longer than BG. Where is the mistake: in what the drawing shows or in the formula that requires proof? In the title you have $\frac {PA}{PB}$ while in the body you have $\frac {BM}{BP}$

Comment: It is an indicative drawing....Sorry for the misunderstanding but i couldn't draw it that precis.

Comment: I think the title has a typo since $\color{red}{PA}\cdot BP=BQ\cdot BG$ does not hold. I think this should be $\color{red}{BM}\cdot BP = BQ \cdot BG$ which Freddy proved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title says $PA\cdot BP=BQ\cdot BG$, but I don't think this holds.

Freddy proved that $BM\cdot BP=BQ\cdot BG$ which can be proved without using coordinate geometry or vectors.

Using [Menelaus's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem) (line $CQP$ passes inside $\triangle{ABN}$), we have
$$\frac{AP}{PB}\times\frac{BQ}{QN}\times\frac{NC}{CA}=1$$
which implies $BQ=QN$, so $Q$ is the midpoint of the line segment $BN$.

Let $BM=a$. Then, since $BP=\frac{2a}{3},BQ=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}a$ and $BG=\frac{2\sqrt 2}{3}a$, we have
$$BM\cdot BP = BQ \cdot BG$$

Answer (score 0):

Let AB = BC = x

M is the midpoint of BC. Hence BM = x/2

Given that PA/PB = 2 or BP/AB = 1/3 or BP = x/3

Hence BM × BP = x/2 × x/3 = x²/6 (LHS)

Now since G is the centroid, BG:GN = 2:1

Or BG:BN = 2/3 or BG = (2/3) × BN

In right angled ∆ABN, A = 45°

Therefore it is isosceles with AN = BN

Now, AN = AC/2 = √2x/2 = x/√2

Hence, BN = x/√2

BG = (2/3) × x/√2 = √2x/3

Since BN bisects B (as ∆ABN and ∆CBN are congruent by SSS case), BQ is the internal angle bisector of B in ∆BPC

So, by internal angle bisector theorem,

QC:QP = BC:BP = 3:1

So point Q divides PC in ratio 1:3

Let the origin be at B (0,0)

Then P(0,x/3) and C(x,0)

Hence Q (x/4,x/4) using section formula

BQ = √2x/4

BQ × BG = √2x/4 × √2x/3 = x²/6 (RHS)

Hence **BM × BP = BQ × BG**

Comment: Heyy!! Thank you soo much for your answer, but I don't know to work with coordinate geometry....Maybe you can do it without it and without vectra. I'm really sorry. Thank you again from the bottom of my heart!

Comment: I have an idea.... maybe we can show that QM is a midline in the traingle NBC or that Q is the midpoint of BN.

Comment: You will need to prove QM || AC for that. Any ideas how will you do that?

Comment: So NM is x/2 and Bm-x/2 so BMN is an right isosceles triangle

Comment: Maybe we can show that QM is perpendicular on BN by showing that it is one of the important lines. The trinahle isosceles will make it the height of the triangle. From there will be easy...

Comment: what do you think? Do you have other ideas?

Comment: so......???????

Comment: Not got any idea till now. Sorry:(

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As you can check in figure the statement is not correct:

$(BP=30)\times (PA=90)\neq( BG=33.94)\times( BQ=56.57)$

Comment: look at the above answer. Thank you for the effort you put into this!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

To see by elementary geometry, that $BM\cdot BP=BG\cdot BQ$, let $AM$ cross $CP$ at $D$, and join $BD$, $PG$.

Since $G$ is the centroid of $\triangle ABC$, and here$$\frac{AG}{GM}=\frac{AP}{PB}=\frac{2}{1}$$then$$PG\parallel BC$$

Since $\angle BPG$ is right, and $PG=PB=\frac{1}{2}AP$, then $B$ lies on the circle through $PGD$, and$$\triangle QBP\sim \triangle QGD$$
[image: BM x BP = BQ x BG]Further, since $\angle GDB$ is right, and$$\frac{DA}{DB}=\frac{PA}{PB}=\frac{2}{1}$$then $DP$ bisects $\angle ADB$, making $\angle GDQ=\angle MBG=45^o$, and thus$$\triangle QGD\sim\triangle MGB$$Therefore$$\triangle QBP\sim\triangle MGB$$that is$$\frac{BM}{BG}=\frac{BQ}{BP}$$and hence$$BM\cdot BP=BG\cdot BQ$$